# Angular mat select overrides the text from the dropodn where the selected value should be showed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 8 with angular material latest version.I have a mat form field,the selection is working etc,but the styles not and it overrides my text where just the selected text shoud go.

Here is the image: https://ibb.co/0YNs21L

In console I dont have warning that angular material theme is not included and here is the angular.json file where iI inputted the angular css theme

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
            ],


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AdminPanelComponent,
    ForbiddenComponent,
    EditProfileComponent,
    SpecificRoleSectionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      progressBar: true
    }),
    FormsModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    // MatToolbarModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [UserService, {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,   
  },
  MatSelectModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule
],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try import angular material theme css in your global styles.css file like this:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

Comment: can you add your app.module.ts file?